# Is there a Micro Four Thirds to Four Thirds Adapter?

Tags: micro-four-thirds, lens-adapter, four-thirds

I've seen several mount adapters that allow you to use a Four Thirds lens on a Micro Four Thirds camera. Is there such an adapter that works in the reverse?

For example, I own a four-thirds camera (an Olympus E520), and I'd like to use a Micro Four Thirds lens. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.*

The micro four thirds to four thirds adaptor is basically a tube which mounts the four thirds lens further from the sensor.

In order to do the reverse you would have to mount the micro four thirds lens *closer* to the sensor, which is not possible as there is stuff in the way!

*at least whilst preserving the ability to focus at moderate distances.